# How to populate the table using JSON and Javascript just below the row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, html-table

I have to populate a table using JSON and Javascript but the data go to next row. Whereas I wish to have data just below the row of column header
Here is my json:

```
 var myList = [{ "Column1": "abc" },
                { "Column2": "25" },
                { "Column3": "xyz" }];
```

The given code fills the data in this sequence :

```
column1  column2 column3
abc               

           25
                   xyz
```

But I wish to have it like :

```
column1  column2 column3
abc        25       xyz
```

Here is my code:

```
  var myList = [{ "Column1": "abc" },
            { "Column2": "25" },
            { "Column3": "xyz" }];
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            buildHtmlTable();            
        });
        function buildHtmlTable()
        {
            var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList); // columns get the name of coluns
            alert("test :  " + myList);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++)
            {
                var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++)
                {

                    var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
                    if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

                    row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                }
                $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

```
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
{
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++)
    {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash)
        {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1)
            {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}
```

and

```
   <table id="excelDataTable" class="contentpanel" border="1"></table>
```

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle or plunker ? Also I am not able to replicate it since addAllColumnHeaders is not defined

Comment: please see the edit part

Comment: Not sure how you are getting the myList.
It is going to next row because you json  is array of three separate object. This below array will but items in one row 
var myList = [ "Column1": "abc" ,"Column2": "25" ,"Column3": "xyz" }];
Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/q19xad1m/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `var row$ = $('<tr/>');` out of the loop. No need for double loop. Try this:

```
var myList = [{ "Column1": "abc" },
            { "Column2": "25" },
            { "Column3": "xyz" }];
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            buildHtmlTable();            
        });
        function buildHtmlTable()
        {
            var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList); // columns get the name of coluns
            //alert("test :  " + myList);
            var row$ = $('<tr/>');
            var colIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++)
            {
                var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
                if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
                row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));

                $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
                colIndex++;
            }
        }

        function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
{
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++)
    {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash)
        {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1)
            {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}
```